# CDN not working on multilingual site

Tags: i18n-l10n, cdn

I have a site that is multilingual using path prefix, for example I can have:

- example.com/en
- example.com/es
- example.com/fr

If the user goes to `example.com`, a language selection page appears (using the language selection module).

But I'm trying to enable the CDN module and it's not working because all resources are pointing to `example.com/sites/.../somecss.css` instead of `example.com/en/sites/...`

If I disable the CDN module the resources are pointed to the correct path.  How can I fix this?  I think it's bug in the CDN module.

Using Drupal 7 & Amazon CloudFront.  I don't want to change the site to subdomain for the languages (eg, `en.example.com`).

Comment: One workaround would be to point CloudFront to something like http://cloudread.example.com and in the htaccess redirect all with that domain to example.com/en, to skip the language selection page.

Comment: Give [AdvAgg](http://drupal.org/project/advagg/) a try. I think it will work correctly for this use case & will work with the CDN module.

Comment: Cool module. Unfortunately it didn't work :(  Even with the CDN disabled, the files point to example.com/sites...

Comment: Bad workaround: so far I've changed `cdn.module`, ln 105 from:
  `$uri = "cdn/farfuture/$token/$ufi/$uri";`
to
  `$uri = "en/cdn/farfuture/$token/$ufi/$uri";`
and it worked.  S*cks as a solution, but it works.

Comment: May I ask why you need the language prefix? I think with advagg everything will work (with no language prefix) unless I'm missing something. AdvAgg will create different css & js aggregates based off of the language used.

Comment: I need the language prefix because I want it to support multiple languages :)  Of course I don't care about the language when requesting a CSS, but the language module redirects to the language selection module when requesting a CSS (or any other URL) that has no prefix.

Comment: Does the undesired redirect happen to the CSS if AdvAgg is used?

Comment: @mikeytown2 yes. Always fails.  I've just discovered that that the redirect to the language selection page is not happening with JPGs.  Don't know why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15020/discussion-between-mikeytown2-and-diego-jancic).

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue the Language Selection Page module is causing the issue https://drupal.org/node/2283985. You can see the styles exemption in [the code](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/language_selection_page/tree/language_selection_page.module?h=7.x-2.x#n88). For you I would add in the advagg and cdn paths to the language_selection_page_blacklisted_paths variable. You should find it under "Paths blacklist" on the `admin/config/regional/language/configure/selection_page` page.

Gotta run will add in the exact paths tomorrow, but it will be something like

> farfuture/*
>   sites/default/files/advagg_css/*
>   sites/default/files/advagg_js/*
>   httprl_async_function_callback